# CSS @media query to include mobile and small browser width

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to write a CSS @media query that will work on both my mobile device and a browser smaller than 500px wide. The following works on my phone but does not work if I resize my browser small.  How do I do that?

```
/* Smartphones and small browsers ----------- */
@media
    all and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    screen and (resolution: 192dpi),
    all and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
    all and (device-aspect-ratio: 9/16) {

/* Styles */
}
/* other devices */
@media
    all and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1),
    screen and (resolution: 96dpi),
    all and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1)
 {
/* Styles */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following line to your media queries:

```
all and (max-width: 500px),
```